# How do I stop a hacked robot from following me?

Tags: fallout-4

I have used the 3rd rank [Robotics Expert perk](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Robotics_Expert#Fallout_4) to hack a robot. This robot belongs to a vault though, and I am now feeling bad for having stolen it, but I can't see any way to tell it to go home. Hacking other robots just seem to expand my entourage, not send the previous robot(s) on their way.

Is there a console command or something that will make the robot stop following me and go home?

Comment: Did you try going back to the terminal? Might be some way to deactivate it.

Comment: There's no terminal involved. The specific robot I'm trying to get rid of in this instance is Old Rusty from Vault 81. The vault need him for all their maintenance, damn it! D: (And apparently I can't mark spoilers in comments. Oh well.) Also, I can always just hack the robot again and shut it down that way, but that won't make the robot go home and continue its job.

Comment: Oh, with the perk. You said that. Was thinking of the Total Hack magazine. You can get some robots to follow you with that. Haven't tried Lvl 3 Robotics Expert. Can you deactivate him or tell him to stay? He basically just sits in the generator room anyway. Could just go back there and tell him to sit.

Comment: I did tell it to stay, and it seemed to stay there for a bit, but then at one point I fast-travelled (I usually don't, but a settlement was under attack…), and Old Rusty suddenly popped up next to me and started to follow me again. I tried to tell it to stay again, but it didn't seem to take. Right now it sits disabled at Oberland Station. But I would still like to give it back to its vault properly, to resume its duties. Seems like they're plenty undermanned even _with_ the robot around. :/

Answer (score 1):

From the [Robotics Expert Wikia page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Robotics_Expert),

> To make a robot commanded with the Rank 3 perk stop following the Sole Survivor, just hack another robot.

It looks like you just need to hack another robot to have it stop following you, but this doesn't specify if it will go back to the vault. However, I did notice the following:

> It is not recommended to hack Percy in Diamond City and use the command option. This will cause him to follow the player character as a companion, potentially getting him killed. There is no way to make him go back to Diamond City permanently.

I'm not sure if it would be the same for a robot you took from a vault or if this is a special case due to it being a named robot.